# How can I read file.xml from the same package?

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read a Properties.xml file which is include in the same package where my class is.

I'm using this code to update my xml file with new values:

So far, just I wanted to read the file:

```
public void UPdateXML(String filename) throws Exception {
    this.filename = filename;
        System.out.println("Into update xml class");
    try {   
        InputStream fis=BACENGPropertiesFile.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse((InputStream) fis);

        System.out.println(fis);
        System.out.println(doc);

    Node child = doc.getFirstChild();
        System.out.println(child);
```

It seems that the file exist and is being reading as an ImputStream. But when I try to parse the file to Document (doc) the value is null.

This is the exit from the server logs:

```
Into update xml class
java.io.BufferedInputStream@78355ed4
[#document: null]
[properties: null]
```

The Properties xml file has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
 <properties>
  <entry key="dataImport.path">/Users/Admin/Documents/</entry>
 </properties>
```

Could somebody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What do you pass as `filename`? It has to be relative, so don't start it with a slash or backslash (since you said it is in the same package).

Comment: I'm passing just the filename "Properties.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. Your document **is not null**: it is printed as:

```
[#document: null]
```

If it would be `null`, this would be printed:

```
null
```

By the way, why don't you load properties via `Properties.loadFromXML()`?

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (InputStream in = BACENGPropertiesFile.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)) {
    p.loadFromXML(in);
}
```

Comment: I'm using it "Properties.loadFromXML()" to get some parameters from this file in others class. But here, what I wanted to do is change some values within the "Properties.xml" file. Therefore I wanted to create a doc and then change parameters using node.setTextContent.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but your `doc` is not `null` as I stated. And also you can read the properties as I showed, change what you want then you can save it back to the file. If you load it with the `DocumentBuilder`, after changing it you also have to save it back so you gain nothing except your solution will be much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I was bit loss ;)

Answer (score 0):

What package do you place the Properties.xml to ? if it's under the package of UPdateXML, please change:

```
InputStream fis=BACENGPropertiesFile.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

to

```
InputStream fis=UPdateXML.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

anyway, What package your xml file locate, what classes under the package you should choose.